# I am not able to install opencv in ubuntu 13.10 and i have mentioned the error i am getting below

Tags: opencv

After giving that command i am getting this... what should i do? this is the first step for creating developer environment. can anyone please give a step by step instruction for installing opencv in ubuntu 13.10 please.

```
ammu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update






Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease                            

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates InRelease                    

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com saucy-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and while giving the below mentioned command am getting the following error what should i do?

```
ammu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install cmake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package cmake is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when the mirror for your software source might not have updates. Try changing software sources in **Ubuntu software center->edit-> software sources -> Downloadfrom**

Then try sudo apt-get update